# Pandas extracting out rows to separate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given this sample dataframe I am trying to extract all rows in which the Code column has a value starting with 'HCC' and all rows that follow until the next 'HCC' into separate dataframes:

```
Code        Description
HCC001      <empty string>
A1          Description of A1
B1          Description of B1
HCC002      <empty string>
A2          Description of A2
B2          Description of B2
C2          Description of C2
HCC003      <empty string>
....
```

I have tried itterrows, just looping through the columns as well.

The expected output is:
Dataframe 1

```
Code        Description
HCC001      <empty string>
A1          Description of A1
B1          Description of B1
```

Dataframe 2

```
Code        Description
HCC002      <empty string>
A2          Description of A2
B2          Description of B2
C2          Description of C2
```

....

This did not work:
hcc_lst = []
#check each row in the first column for 'HCC' and make a separate dataframe

```
for i in range(len(icd_data)):
    if 'HCC' in icd_data.iloc[i,0]:
        hcc_lst.append(icd_data.iloc[i,0])
```

I am sure that something with itterrows should work I just cannot find this precise answer.

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create groups and use `locals()` to create new python variables dynamically (strongly discouraged, maybe your should use a dictionary to store sub dataframes):

```
for i, subdf in df.groupby(df['Code'].str.startswith('HCC').cumsum()):
    locals()[f"df{i}"] = subdf
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
     Code        Description
0  HCC001     <empty string>
1      A1  Description of A1
2      B1  Description of B1

>>> df2
     Code        Description
3  HCC002     <empty string>
4      A2  Description of A2
5      B2  Description of B2
6      C2  Description of C2

>>> df3
     Code     Description
7  HCC003  <empty string>
```

Comment: Wow, @Corralien.  This worked perfectly.  Yes, I did save the dfs in a dictionary by their name, etc.  Thank you so much for this.  Saved me hours (if I ever would have figured it out).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using [eq](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) for checking rows starting with "HCC" and [cumsum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) to segregate the DataFrames likewise:

```
for k, v in df.groupby(df['Code'].str[:3].eq('HCC').cumsum()):
    print(f"DataFrame {k}")
    print(v)
    print('\n')
```

Comment: I didn't have a chance to try this but I will.  The first answer worked for me.  Thank you for taking the time to contribute.